# Fancy cloud quote-Arithmetic overflow

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, csquotes

I ws trying to make a fancy quote...(Any ideas?) I couldn't find annything, so I thought of using a cloud... My code is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

   \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%\begin{exampleblock}{}
%  {\large ``There is something rotten in the state of our detector.''}
% \end{exampleblock}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[align=center,color=gray!20, draw,fill=gray!20, text=red, cloud callout, cloud     puffs=20, cloud puff arc=145, callout pointer segments=0, anchor=pointer, callout relative     pointer={(0:5 cm )}, aspect=4,scale=0.5] at (0,0) {\textbf{\large ``There is something     rotten in the state of our detector.''}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}%<------------error at that line

\end{document}
```

The thing is that I get an error stating that there is an arithmetic overflow. The cloud is produsecf, though. So my question has to do with `What is this arithmetic overflow` and `Any fancy quotes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider working out a minimal example as it would really emphasize the problem stronger. The problem can be cut down to the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[align=center,
        gray!20, draw,fill, text=red, 
        cloud callout, cloud puffs=20, cloud puff arc=145, callout pointer segments=1, 
        anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(0:1 cm )}, aspect=4,
        scale=0.5] 
        at (0,0) 
        {\textbf{\large ``There is something rotten in the state of our detector.''}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the reason for the error is that you have set the pointer segments to 0 which makes it simply a `cloud` not a `cloud callout` or thinking balloon. So there must be at least one segment to prevent the error.

Also as previously mentioned you are using options that are obsolete now. Look at your warning messages after the compilation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[align=center,gray!20, draw,fill, text=red, 
        cloud, cloud puffs=10, aspect=4,scale=0.5] 
        at (0,0) 
        {\textbf{\large ``There is something rotten in the state of our detector.''}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working!!! Any idea of a fancy quote? Baloon or Sticky Postit?